# convert bytes into hexadecimal in python

Tags: python

I am trying to multiply two data of bytes data type using python by trying to converting them into hexadecimal values. but it seems that the hex() function is not working. Can you please help me on that. Below is my code (x and y are our data of type bytes)

```
data=bytes.hex(x) * bytes.hex(y)
```

I am getting the error: TypeError:'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

by trying

```
data = hex(x) * hex(y)
```

the error become:  TypeError:'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Can anyone help please?

Comment: can you show us x and y ? also what happens if you try `data = hex(int(x)) * hex(int(y))` ?

Comment: x=/\x12>\xb3\x96\xbd\x0c\xc8s\xad\x04\x08\xd7nJ\x8f\xa8\x06\x1d\xeb6s@(\xbf\xee\x89<\xbe%\xc02x\xf7\xc2\x11\x06*\x9d\xab;pw\xdf\xed\xc9\xf2\x80\xa0i9\xb28E\xd2\x0c\xb4\xf6\x8f\x1f\\\x9d\x97V1\xd7x3)\xa5\xb1\xa4\xc6@!\x9d\xc8\xd0p\x15;M\xb9\xd9u\t\x13\xd4\t ;"y\xf7\x1c\xe1\xce\xc7}p\x87\xe7\x9b\x1a\x81\xa6\x9cU\x9a5}\x04\xba\xd2\xf9-\xce\xcbJ\xc9\xb20\xa2\x89\xb0\x8d_\xe1\xdcZ\x1a\xa3sx\x9cf}\xd4\xdd\xd5(~\x04\xdc\xc9]\x0f \xa9\x00e8\xe8\xd5\xb3\x96\x18\xa7\xef\xb7\x97\x02P\xb3\x06f(\x97\x10\x8f\x05\n\xf4nD\xf7\xd3Z\xba&Piv4\t\x93\xc9\xfa\x8a\xc7\x84X \xf7&\t\x9a\xb5\x14\xf2\x96\xd3

Comment: y=443092307039640785254974185821665870069111371454869779595614781250913657568315191209896495992412314727468687190612818318215304256948374109895189492055497919831470827136711515028626702325616084418119873093709649785866067819256974069584443925745791483800181069601840135638251987153228657607949544611194941628123458990705502915848639557055978627468546960283049085759182207757975757952207108317018204086309222971046911427205962504111782964600981164650566114717307048577811637958868774956482801819432376638086821998480077279962434373789165332103718671806603152832476096421293453715460993156167445542686

Comment: @GraceUwimana, if you're trying to interpret those long byte arrays as arbitrary length integers, please take a look at my answer and see if it might be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

`hex(my_var)` returns a string. To do math you need to convert your variables to int:

```
x_int = int(x, base=16)
y_int = int(y, base=16)

decimal_value = x_int * y_int # integer
hex_value = hex(decimal_value) # string
```

Comment: with int(x,base=16) the error changes to ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16

Comment: Convert your bytes array to a hex string using `bytes.hex(x)` and then convert that value to int

Comment: Thank you team! I encrypted the bytes into string and then in int before the multiplication and it works t= bytes.hex(x) , l =bytes.hex(y), m=int(l,16)*int(t,16)

Answer (score 0):

> `data = hex(x) * hex(y)`

This doesn't work because the `hex()` function expects an int as an argument and outputs a string.

In Python 3, you can do the following (interprets bytes as base 10)

```
data = hex(int(x)*int(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

I see in the comments below your question that you have examples of your x and y values - you have some *very* large numbers to process if you interpret the bytes objects as arbitrary length integers. Not sure this is what you want, but this will do conversion of bytes to/from integer values.

```
>>> int_x = int.from_bytes(x, 'big')              # From bytes to int.
>>> int_y = int.from_bytes(y, 'big')
>>> int_z = int_x * int_y                         # int_z as an integer.
>>>
>>> # Converting int_z to a bytes object:
>>>
>>> bytes_length = (int_z.bit_length() + 7) // 8
>>>
>>> z = int_z.to_bytes(bytes_length, 'big')
```

If you want them interpreted as little endian, replace 'big' with 'little'.

If your `y` value is already an int type, which it looks like in your comment, then don't convert it before multiplying:

```
>>> int_x = int.from_bytes(x, 'big')
>>> int_y = y
>>> int_z = int_x * int_y
>>> z     = int_z.to_bytes(bytes_length, 'big')
```

The first parameter to `int.to_bytes()` is the length of the `bytes` object to create. There are other ways to calculate this value, but the way I included is the fastest method out of 3 that I timed.

If all you wanted to do was convert a `bytes` object to its hex string representation (`z` below is treated as a `bytes` object):

```
>>> hex_z = '0x' + ''.join(hex(b)[2:] for b in z)
```

Or to convert an `int` to a hex string:

```
>>> hex_z = hex(int_z)
```

`hex()` can handle very large integers.